# Trouble processing Shopify liquid in metafield data

Tags: metadata, shopify, liquid

I am trying to find a way to process Shopify's liquid templating language inside of metafield data.

For example, if I have this in the page.liquid file:

```
{% assign example_var = page.metafields.namespace_here.injected_template %}
{{ example_var }}
```

*In this case, injected_template = "The current template is: {{ template }}."*

This will output: The current template is: {{ template }}.

However, if I do a replace in the 'assign' line I can replace a single liquid object (or more if I add more replace filters).

```
{% assign example_var = page.metafields.namespace_here.injected_template | replace: '{{ template }}', template %}
{{ example_var }}
```

Now, the output is: The current template is: page.

This is a start in the right direction for processing liquid template language that's in metafields, and I can do replace filters for the basic liquid objects (which could add up to a lot of replace filters), but I can't figure out how to do more complex templates with "if" or "for" statments or use filters in the metafield like this: The current template is: {{ template | capitalize }}.

Having this capability would add a lot of flexibility to an App that I'm working on.

Comment: Remember, any value for a metafield is stored as a string or an integer. So what you are looking at is literally impossible without using `replace`. You have also not provided any use case for this.

Comment: I feel there is a more sensible way of achieving what you are trying to do. What is the use case?

Comment: Are you asking in the context of building an app? It might be that a proxy page will get you what you want: https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies